# How to read the local image file via javascript in ie9 or ie8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, file-io

I want read a local file picture via java-script in ie9 or ie8. Is that possible?

I just want to read the  object and show it in 
I find ie8 and ie9 partly support

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEAAAABACAI
AAAFSDNYfAAAAaklEQVR42u3XQQrAIAwAQeP%2F%2F6wf8CJBJTK9lnQ7FpHGaOurt1
I34nfH9pMMZAZ8BwMGEvvh%2BBsJCAgICLwIOA8EBAQEBAQEBAQEBK79H5RfIQAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAID%2FABMSqAfj%2FsLmvAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg%3D%3D">
```

I want read the binary file and transform it into above form string. 
In that way I can show local picture.

I just want support ie8 and ie9. I have finished the ff part, the customer want to support ie8 and ie9

Comment: Did you try with `<input type="file">`?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you trying to load a picture in an <img> tag or are you just wanting to open the file and view it in a separate window?

Comment: Javascript (at least when running in a browser) does not have access to the client's file system, in case your question pertains to that.

Comment: @Asad, the File API lets you read "blobs" from the local file system and display images directly in the browser, however IE9- does not support it.

Comment: I just want know how ie8 or ie9 read files

Comment: @user504909 it can’t, not using JavaScript in the browser.

Comment: That is either awesome or terrifying. Is this HTML5?

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: They don't have access to the actual OS. Javascript only affects thing s in the browser window. What is your end game on this? Do you wanna show a picture on your web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, JavaScript doesn't have this feature.

Because we accessing local file system. So for the security reason we can't see folder structure or uploaded file path in JavaScript.

Comment: do not think ie as security as you describe:

Comment: This has little to do with javascript as a language, more of a browser security measure. F.ex the HTML5 File API let’s you access local images and display them as data blobs. However, not all browsers supports it.

Comment: obj.select();var source=document.selection.createRange().text; that code can get file name in ie8

Comment: I just want support ie8 and ie9. I have finished the ff part, the customer want support ie8 and ie9

Answer (score 2):

YES YOU CAN (as some weird guy I hardly know would say)... YES YOU CAN read and write binary files in Javascript with Internet Explorer using **FSO/OpenTextFile** through ActiveX. Indeed, I even have written a Javascript "*Fichier*" (I'm French) class that allows Internet Explorer to open local files in various modes, including direct access mode, providing  Seek(position), Read(numberOfBytes), Write(string), and Save changes on demand.

It can also, for example, load a whole file into a string and convert it into Base-64: This allows to load image files directly from the local disk rather than making them get uploaded by some web server and download back to the client afterwards: Isn't it strange indeed, to think that to go from 
West London to Centre London , you are obliged to go first from West London to Glasgow and then back from Glasgow to Centre London ?

The point is that **you simply have to know a little secret**, without which you won't be able to write all bytes to your disk, nor convert your loaded file into Base-64. I'm just going to tell you that secret, considering the two following points:

. First, you have to read your file byte by byte, instead of readAll() or read(n) where n>1. That way, you prevent the browser from associating several bytes in some cases. So you'll make a loop with "objectFile.Read(1)" inside.

. Secondly, here's the secret: among the 256 characters of the ASCII+ table (extended to the 8th bit), 27 of them have an abnormal behaviour which is THE ONLY THING that prevents you from manipulating binary files:
These 27 characters are located in the range of 2 "paragraphs", that is 32 bytes going from 128 to 159 (80h to 9Fh), except for 5 of them: 129,141,143,144,157 : These 5 behave normally.
But for the 27 other bytes of that range of 32, as soon as they are being read from the disk, they are changed into 16-bit values: For example, the Euro symbol is supposed to be character 128 (80h) in UTF-8, and it is, indeed, the value for which it is written in your file. But in the browser's memory, it is turned into a 16-bit value: 8364(20ACh) as soon as you read the 80h byte from the disk.

To understand this, try the following code, assuming you can write on your "D:\" directory, otherwise change the code to designate another directory, on which your browser is authorized to write.

```
<script type="text/javascript'>
    fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    oFich = fso.OpenTextFile("d:\\foo.txt", 2, true);
    var c1 = String.fromCharCode(65); // 65 is the ASCII code for "A"
    oFich.write(c1);
    oFich.close();
</script>
```

After having executed that code, you'll find a "foo.txt" file on your disk: Open it in your textpad and you'll see a perfect "A".

Now, on 3rd line of the Javascript code above, you can replace the value "65" by any other value, for example "66" will write "B" into your foo.txt file, "97" will write "a", "55" will write "7" and so on... But now, try it with the value "128": It becomes unpleasant, because you're being insulted by your browser! Like this:

```
                    "Incorrect argument or procedure call"
```

Well, all you wanted was to write the "€" symbol into your file. Why can't you do that? because THE VALUE 128 CAN NOT BE WRITTEN AS IS THROUGH FSO. AND SO ARE THE 26 OTHER VALUES mentioned above. By the way, don't conclude that it is the 8th bit that causes that failure, since 128 is the first 8 bit number : If you replace 128 by any number between 160 and 255, which also has bit-7 set on, you'll be able to see that it works perfectly well.

So, now try this:

```
fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
oFich = fso.OpenTextFile("d:\\foo.txt", 2, true);
var c1 = String.fromCharCode(8364); // 8364  (unicode for "€" symbol ?)
oFich.write(c1);
oFich.close();
```

You'll be satisfied to notice there is no more error message after execution. Then, type your "foo.txt" and you'll see a beautiful "€" symbol. But what will surprise you is, that if you load that file into a hexadecimal "dumper" tool, you'll see that the code is not "AC 20" (8364) but "80"(128) !

Knowing that, you can now convert any string of bytes into Base-64 or write any string of bytes to a file, as soon as you know that to write the "128" byte to your disk, YOU HAVE NO OTHER MEANS THAN REPLACING IT by 8364 (20ACh). No problem by the way if you really want to write 8364(20ACh): But that means your file is a combination of 16-bit values instead of a simple range of bytes. So you'll simply write the two bytes combining that number, writing the low byte first:

```
      oFich.write(String.fromCharCode(172)); // 172 = ACh
      oFich.write(String.fromCharCode(32));  //  32 = 20h
```

In so far as you manipulate text only, you have nothing to do: The "€" is not written the same way in your browser's memory and on your disk, but it remains a "€" anyway, so it is transparent. But if you load the byte 128 for its number value, well, there you'll have a problem, because you'll get 8364 instead of every 128 you will read from the file: This is why many people fail when they try to encode base-64 in Javascript.

In fact, you just have to filter the 27 dooming characters when you want them to take their numeric values. This is why I have written the two following functions, that I use in some parts of my "*Fichier*" class, where they are needed, and in my Base-64 algorithm,  when I load the image file directly from the client disk, or when I have to manipulate bytes as numbers instead of characters:

These two functions cancel out the partial "*perversion*" of their Javascript models:

```
                    `String.fromCharcode() and String.charCodeAt()`
```

As they simply encapsulate their models, I gave them the classical Basic names: "asc" and "chr", so they are easy both to understand and to remember. Here they are:

```
function asc(c) //(string)->integer
{   // Objet : Renvoie le code ASCII du 1er caractère de la chaine "c"
    var i = c.charCodeAt(0);
    if (i < 256)
        return i;       // caractères ordinaires
    // (plage 128-159 excepté les 5 caractères 129,141,143,144,157, qui fonctionnent normalement)
    switch (i) {
        case 8364:      // "€" 
            return 128
        case 8218:
            return 130
        case 402:
            return 131
        case 8222:
            return 132
        case 8230:
            return 133
        case 8224:
            return 134
        case 8225:
            return 135
        case 710:
            return 136
        case 8240:
            return 137
        case 352:
            return 138
        case 8249:
            return 139
        case 338:
            return 140
        case 381:
            return 142
        case 8216:
            return 145
        case 8217:
            return 146
        case 8220:
            return 147
        case 8221:
            return 148
        case 8226:
            return 149
        case 8211:
            return 150
        case 8212:
            return 151
        case 732:
            return 152
        case 8482:
            return 153
        case 353:
            return 154
        case 8250:
            return 155
        case 339:
            return 156
        case 382:
            return 158
        case 376:
            return 159
        default:
            return -1       // provoquera une erreur, le cas ne devant pas se présenter
    }
}
function chr(octet) //->(integer)->string
{   // Objet  : renvoie le caractère d'un nombre 8 bits
    // Entrée : "octet" est un nombre 8 bits non signé (entre 0 et 255)
    // Sortie : le caractère correspondant est renvoyé, les codes échappés sont rattrapés par un switch
    if (octet < 128) || (octet > 159))
        return String.fromCharCode(octet);     // caractères ordinaires, traités par String.fromCharCode
    switch (octet) {
        case 128:
            return "€"
        case 129:
            return String.fromCharCode(129);
        case 130:
            return "‚"
        case 131:
            return "ƒ"
        case 132:
            return "„"
        case 133:
            return "…"
        case 134:
            return "†"
        case 135:
            return "‡"
        case 136:
            return "ˆ"
        case 137:
            return "‰"
        case 138:
            return "Š"
        case 139:
            return "‹"
        case 140:
            return "Œ"
        case 141:
            return String.fromCharCode(141);
        case 142:
            return "Ž"
        case 143:
            return String.fromCharCode(143);
        case 144:
            return String.fromCharCode(144);
        case 145:
            return "‘"
        case 146:
            return "’"
        case 147:
            return "“"
        case 148:
            return "”"
        case 149:
            return "•"
        case 150:
            return "–"
        case 151:
            return "—"
        case 152:
            return "˜"
        case 153:
            return "™"
        case 154:
            return "š"
        case 155:
            return "›"
        case 156:
            return "œ"
        case 157:
            return String.fromCharCode(157);
        case 158:
            return "ž"
        case 159:
            return "Ÿ"
        default:
            return String.fromCharCode(octet);         // unicode 16 bits
    }
}
```

Now, you can binary read and write any type of file with Internet Explorer using ActiveX, on every zone of your disks where you have allowed IE to touch files.

As the great and missed French humorist Pierre Desproges used to say: "*Etonnant, non?*"

BB.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on David's comment - MS promised support for FileAPI standard for IE10.
The rest of the browser pack are far more ahead on HTML5.

For IE8-9, you'd probably have to use a plugin like ActiveX or Flash's SWFObject